# How to do conditional joins on SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables with below data

Table1

```
Id      Val Version
1.06    M   1
1.07    N   1
1.08    S   1
```

Table2

```
Id1     Val1    Version1
1.06    M       1
1.06    CAA     1
1.07    N       1
1.08    CAA     1
```

I want to get all the records from `table1` and `table2` having
same Id, Version and if `Val` from `table1` is found in `table2` then only return that row or else return the record if `val="CAA"`

To explain it:

```
select *
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2
    on t1.id=t2.id1
   and t1.version=t2.vesrion1

Case
  If t1.val=t2.val (only return that row)

else
  if t2.val="CAA" return this
```

The final output should be like this:

```
Id      Val Version Id1     Val1    Version1
1.06    M   1       1.06    M       1
1.07    N   1       1.07    N       1
1.08    S   1       1.08    CAA     1
```

I have managed to write a query like below which gives me partial result

```
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id1 and t1.val=t2.val1 and t1.version=t2.version1
  left join table2 t3 ON t1.id=t3.id1 and t3.val1="CAA" and t1.version=t3.version1 and t2.id1 is null;

+---+---+-------+----+----+--------+----+----+--------+
|id |val|version|id1 |val1|version1|id1 |val1|version1|
+---+---+-------+----+----+--------+----+----+--------+
|1  |a  |1      |1   |a   |1       |null|null|null    |
|2  |b  |1      |2   |b   |1       |null|null|null    |
|3  |c  |1      |null|null|null    |3   |CAA |1       |
+---+---+-------+----+----+--------+----+----+--------+
```

I am not sure how to filter records from here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.Id = t2.Id1 AND t1.Val = t2.Val1)
)
SELECT * FROM x
 UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.Id = t2.Id1 AND t2.Val1 = 'CAA')
 WHERE t1.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM x)
```